# Why does my content object not show up in the portal_catalog?

Tags: plone, zope

I am trying to implement a basic Zope2 content type directly without using dexterity or Archetypes because I need this to be extremely lean.

```python
from OFS.SimpleItem import SimpleItem
from Products.ZCatalog.CatalogPathAwareness import CatalogAware
from persistent.list import PersistentList

class Doculite(SimpleItem, CatalogAware):
    """ implement our class """

    meta_type = 'Doculite'

    def __init__(self, id, title="No title", desc=''):
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.desc = desc
        self.tags = PersistentList()
        self.default_catalog = 'portal_catalog'

    def add_tags(self, tags):
        self.tags.extend(tags)

    def Subject(self):
        return self.tags

    def indexObject(self):
        self.reindex_object()
```

From an external method I am doing this:

```python
def doit(self):
    pc = self.portal_catalog
    res1 = pc.searchResults()
    o1 = self['doc1']
    o1.add_tags(['test1', 'test2'])
    o1.reindex_object()
    res2 = pc.searchResults()
    return 'Done'
```

I clear the catalog and run my external method. My object does not get into the catalog. But from the indexes tab, when I browse the Subject index, I can see my content item listed with the values. Both res1 and res2 and empty.

Why is my content item not showing up inside the searchResuts() of the catalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plone needs every content object to provide an "allowedRolesAndUsers" index to return the object in searchResults.

There is probably a zcml snippet that will enable this for my content type. But I was able to get things working by adding another method as follows:

```
def allowedRolesAndUsers(self):
    return ['Manager', 'Authenticated', 'Anonymous']
```

Answer (score 2):

Plone is a full-fat content management system, if you're after something lean it's probably not the right choice (perhaps try Pyramid.)

For your content type to be a full part of a Plone site it has to fulfil a number of requirements across the Zope2, CMF and Plone layers. plone.app.content.item.Item is about the simplest base class you can get for a content item for a Plone site, though a simpler base class in itself will not really make instances of your content type any more 'lean' - an instance of a class in Python is basically just a dict and a pointer to it's class.

Most of the work on a page view will be rendering the various user interface features of a site. Rendering the schema based add/edit forms of frameworks like Archetypes and Dexterity is also relatively expensive.

I'd spend a little time profiling your application using one of the supported content type systems before putting time into building your own.

Comment: My content type works! Just not able to store it in the catalog. If I could do that I will be sailing!!

Comment: too much baggage in plone.app.content.item.. especially the dublincore stuff

Answer (score 0):

In order to see your objects in the "Catalog" tab of the portal_catalog your objects need to have a "`getPhysicalPath()`" method that returns a tuple representing their path (ex. `('','Plone','myobject')`).
Also try to use this:

```python
from Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware import CMFCatalogAware
```

as base class.

Comment: It is derived from SimpleItem so getPhysicalPath() is implemented. I tried deriving from CMFCatalogAware also but it did not make a difference except for providing the plone.indexer wrapper (from the code path in CMFPlone.CatalogTool).

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your type with the catalog multiplexer. Look at the configuration in the zmi -> archetypes_tool.

I'm not sure, but you may also need a portal_type registration also...

Like Lawrence said though, you're better off just using one of the current content type frameworks if you want to be able to catalog your data with plone's portal catalog. If you can deal with a separate catalog, take a look at repoze.catalog.

Comment: Does the Plone Catalog tool require that my type be registered with the catalog multiplexer in Archetype tool? Will check that although I cannot begin to guess why it would want that.

Comment: Dug into the code but don't see where this is enforced... So don't think this is an issue

Answer (score 0):

CatalogAware will be removed in Zope 4 and then can't be used any more.

cf https://github.com/zopefoundation/Products.ZCatalog/issues/26